# Is there a way to read hidden text in Microsoft Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, hidden

I am trying to populate a word template in C#. The template contains a table with several cells. I need to be able to identify each cell based on a unique id. I do not find a way to store & read a unique id for each cell/text in word. My approach is to have the unique id as hidden text in each cell. And then format the cell (like changing the background color) based on this unique id.

I face the problem in reading this hidden text in each cell in C#?

Any suggestions would be of great help please!

Thanks!

Comment: You are cute, but we need to see a peace of code instead :_(

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed able to resolve this by having the bookmarks stored in the word file and then reading them in the code. I am still working on the complete functionality and will come back with the code if I get stuck again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here it comes! You can iterate over a document and find a hidden text:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range p in objDoc.Range().Words)
{
    if (p.Font.Hidden != 0) //Hidden text found
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

The values returned for `p` are:

  0: Text visible

  -1: Text Hidden

That's what I did for a Word Document, but if you are able to iterate over your cells' content, probably this information may help you.

Answer (score 1):

To read hidden text in your code you just need to set

```
rangeObject.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeHiddenText = true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make them visible for example, you can iterate trough all words and check the Font.Hidden property, then set it visible:

```
Word.Document document = ThisAddIn.Instance.Application.ActiveDocument;
var rangeAll = document.Range();
                rangeAll.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeHiddenText = true;
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range p in rangeAll.Words)
                {                   
                    texts += p.Text;
                    if (p.Font.Hidden != 0) //Hidden text found
                    {
                        p.Font.Hidden = 0;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
```